# some confusion on git pull vs git-fetch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

So - can someone clarify this one:

I run:

```
git pull origin master  
git status
```

And it then pulls the changes and says:

```
your branch is ahead of origin/master ... blahblah by 6 commits...
```

When I then run

```
git fetch
git status
```

It says:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So - I thought `git pull` does git fetch by default - so why does it says "ahead by 6 commits"  without additional `git fetch`?

Comment: In this particular case it means what it says: your branch is ahead, i.e. contains unpushed commits, which has nothing to do with the pull, it's just a heads-up for you.

Comment: @bredikhin But I've just pulled these commits - why in the world would they be classified as un-pushed? That's where I'm confused. Why when I pull changes from a remote branch I don't just get a message "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" right away?

Comment: is it possible that before you ran `git status` the second time, you ran `git push`?

Comment: @Dannyboy Your local commits are un-pushed, not those you have pulled.

Comment: @bredikhin But I don't have any local commits. And if I do `git fetch` - after `git pull` -> this message doesn't come up, I just get "nothing to commit (working directory clean)"

Comment: It is also possible that your branch `master` is not tracking `origin/master`. So you get this output when you run `git pull origin master`, but not `git status`. Can you please post your `.git/config` file contents?

Comment: @Dannyboy Because `fetch` refreshes remote branch (`origin/master`) on your local machine, and `pull` merges directly to your local `master` branch.

Comment: @bredikhin But from documentation: "In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`". So pull does fetch as well - am I wrong?

Comment: @micromoses http://paste.ubuntu.com/6562613/

Comment: `git remote show origin`; `git branch -u origin/master master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ahead or behind by X commits" text in `git status` is based on the state of the tracking branch for the current branch; `remotes/origin/master` if you're on `master`, for example.

When you run `git pull` with both a remote and a branch specified, it fetches the new commits and merges them in to the current branch, but it does *not* update origin's remote tracking branches. Instead, it points to the just-fetched commits as `FETCH_HEAD`.

Running `git fetch` with no arguments specified, on the other hand, *does* update all of the remote tracking branches, so it makes the message go away. `git pull` with no arguments does the same.

A subtle gotcha that I've hit a bunch of times myself! I wish git updated all remote tracking branches on every fetch against a particular remote, instead.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know *why* `git pull <remote> <branch>` does not update the *`remote/branch`* ref?  Is it just Hysterical Raisins, or is there some good reason?

Comment: It turns out that it actually isn't `git pull <remote> <branch>` at all; it's really `git pull <remote> <refspec>`. A "refspec" is basically a source-destination pair separated by a colon, like `master:origin/master`; `git pull origin master:origin/master` means "go to the origin remote, give me its master branch, and update origin/master in the local repository." If you leave off the colon, the fetch won't update any local refs at all, just `FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: Further reading: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec